# CSS animation rotating in unexpected way

Tags: css, css-animations

I feel like my junior high math is failing me.

I want to rotate two `div`s around the Y axis in different directions. I have created these two animations:

```
@-webkit-keyframes first{
    0%   { -webkit-transform: rotateY(0); }
  100% { -webkit-transform: rotateY(-90deg); }
}

@-webkit-keyframes second{
    0%   { -webkit-transform: rotateY(0);}
  100% { -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg); }
}
```

There has been some confusion about my original fiddle, so I've updated it with an image. Each of the two `div`'s will display half the image. My thought is that each half of the image would rotate in opposite directions around the y-axis until they both disappear. That does not appear to be happening, they appear to be rotating together.

Here's the fiddle (Chrome only):

http://jsfiddle.net/eveQt/7/

Comment: You want it so the 'first' transforms inwards, and 'second' transforms outwards?

Comment: They are going in the opposite direction. It's just our perspective.

Comment: @BillCriswell I realized it would appear that way, I just added some text to the divs in my fiddle to help.

Comment: is this what you are looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/eveQt/3/

Comment: @metsales Close... I want them to start on the same plane, then have one rotate "clockwise" while the other rotates "counter-clockwise"

Comment: @ChrisHardie I could just be brain dead today, but do you want it to spin or just have them going opposite directions?

Comment: @ChrisHardie how about this one? http://jsfiddle.net/eveQt/4/

Comment: @metsales I've updated the fiddle with an image which I hope makes things more clear. Why do the two images rotate together? I would have thought one image would be rotated from the right edge straight up, while the other would be rotated from the left edge. In this animation, both images appear to be lifted from the left edge, and I don't understand why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are going in opposite directions

add perspective to see it better

```
.space {
    -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eveQt/8/)

Answer (score 1):

Use this as CSS to see the difference:

```
.first{
    -webkit-animation: first 5s infinite;
}

.second{
    -webkit-animation: second 5s infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes first{
    0%   { -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0.1,0.5,0.1,0deg); }
  50% { -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0.1,0.5,0.1,-90deg); }
  100% { -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0.1,0.5,0.1,-180deg); }
}

@-webkit-keyframes second{
    0%   { -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0.1,0.5,0.1,0deg); }
  50% { -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0.1,0.5,0.1,90deg); }
  100% { -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0.1,0.5,0.1,180deg); }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure they are rotating in opposite directions. Anyways you will never be able to tell. It is an optical illusion